# Understanding firebase security rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have some difficulties to completely understand how the firebase security system is working. My backend is managed with firebase cloud functions. I am not using firebase authentication but i have my own custom JWT auth system. My requests are protected only by the token generated by an authenticated user.

In firebase, i set my security rules for my database like this :

`allow read, write: if request.auth != null;`

I have 3 questions :

1. How firebase can know that the user is authenticated since i am not using the firebase auth system but my own JWT ?
2. Can i provide a full protection to my database only with json web tokens and don't set correctly the security rules in firebase ?
3. When i started my project, i register my `localhost` as a trusted domai in order to make local test of my firebase cloud functions. Does it mean that anybody that got my database url can make operations to my database from his own localhosted application ?

Comment: If you're not using Firebase Authentication on the client side if your app, all data protected by `request.auth != null` will be inaccessible.  `request.auth` is only available when used with Firebase Auth.

Comment: Ok thanks. so if i understand, firebase admin handle automatically all securities concerns, so no need to set up additional security rules, is that correct ?

Comment: Access to Firebase and Cloud products by server SDKs (include the Fireabse Admin SDK) bypass all security rules all the time.

Comment: Thanks ! I have a last question. Can someone (malicious person) initialize a new firebase project by specifiying my database url as his own database in order to have a read/write access to my data ? I registered localhost as a trusted domain so does it mean that anybody that got my database url can make operations  from his own localhosted application ?

Comment: @DougStevenson Please post your comment as an answer.